# How to label only once when plotting multiple longitudinal trajectories in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, label, geom-text

I have done a plot with multiple trajectories like the one in the image https://i0.wp.com/svbtleusercontent.com/xcexi7wk8xsj1w_small.png?w=456&ssl=1
Let's use it as a reproducible example:

```
library(ourworldindata)
id <- financing_healthcare %>% 
     filter(continent %in% c("Oceania", "Europe") & between(year, 2001, 2005)) %>% 
     select(continent, country, year, health_exp_total) %>% 
     na.omit()
ggplot(id, aes(x = year, y = health_exp_total, group = country, color = continent)) +
     geom_line()
```

If I want to add the labels of the countries in the plot I make

```
ggplot(id, aes(x = year, y = health_exp_total, group = country, color = continent, label= country)) +
     geom_line()+geom_text()
```

But thus, the labels appear repeated for each year and overlapped with others. Is it possible that each label appear for only a year and avoiding overlapping?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: To avoid overlapping labels you can use [`ggrepel`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#devtools::install_github('drsimonj/ourworldindata')
library(ourworldindata)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

id <- financing_healthcare %>% 
  filter(continent %in% c("Oceania", "Europe") & between(year, 2001, 2005)) %>% 
  select(continent, country, year, health_exp_total) %>% 
  na.omit()

idl = id %>% filter(year == 2005)
ggplot(id, aes(x = year, y = health_exp_total, group = country, color = continent)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text_repel(data=idl, aes(label=country), size=2.5)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgWFG.png)